# reading data from one array and writing data to another array, google charts implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova

Sorry for the noob question but I'm having trouble working with arrays in javascript. I'm reading BLE data from an arduino in 2 byte packets and storing the assembled data in an array. Basically the arduino sends the current temp reading over BLE and it's stored in an array.

```
        // Start reading notifications.
        evothings.ble.enableNotification(
        deviceHandle,
        app.characteristicRead,
        function(data)
        {
            app.displayStatus('Active');
            app.drawLines([new DataView(data).getUint16(0, true)]);
        },
        function(errorCode)
        {
            app.displayStatus('enableNotification error: ' + errorCode);
        });
```

the data is then displayed in a 2d line graph

```
drawLines: function(dataArray)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataPoints = app.dataPoints;

    dataPoints.push(dataArray);
    if (dataPoints.length > canvas.width)
    {
        dataPoints.splice(0, (dataPoints.length - canvas.width));
    }

    var magnitude = 1200;

    function calcY(i)
    {
        return (i * canvas.height) / magnitude;
    }

    function drawLine(offset, color)
    {
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, calcY(dataPoints[dataPoints.length-1][offset]));
        var x = 1;
        for (var i = dataPoints.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var y = calcY(dataPoints[i][offset]);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            x++;
        }
        context.stroke();
    }

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawLine(0, '#f00');
},
```

This all works fine but I'd like to adapt this code to display the current temp (last entry in the data array) as a google chart (gauge).

```
    // Start reading notifications.
    evothings.ble.enableNotification(
        deviceHandle,
        app.characteristicRead,
        function(data)
        {
            app.drawChart([new DataView(data).getUint16(0, true)]);
        },
        function(errorCode)
        {
            console.log('enableNotification error: ' + errorCode);
        });
```

and

```
drawChart: function(dataArray) {

    var chartdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Temp', 0]
        ]);

    var options = {
      width: 800, height: 240,
      redFrom: 900, redTo: 1200,
      yellowFrom:750, yellowTo: 900,
      greenFrom:550, greenTo: 750,
      minorTicks: 5,
      max: 1200,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(chartdata, options);

    setInterval(function() {
    var temp = dataArray.slice(-1)[0];
    chartdata.setValue(0, 1, temp);
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);
    }, 1000);

  },
```

This adapted code works but in a weird way. Initially the chart stays at zero, if I restart the arduino the temp updates but only once and stays at the value even though the arduino is sending new values. I think I wrote the adapted code wrong but not really sure what I'm doing. I barely know C++ and tried to figure out how to adapt this js for my project.

I'm using this function to take the last entry from the array, not sure if this is correct:

```
dataArray.slice(-1)[0]
```

I know it's a js issue, when I run the initial code with 2d line graph everything works fine and the data is continuously updated. Both charts pull from the same BLE data array so the problem should be in my js code.

Thanks for any advice